# Filter result after $graphLookup pipeline stage

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have parent and child records that are identical in fields. However certain fields are only set at a parent level.

The parent field set to an empty string ("") signifies that the record is a parent. The other records have a value set which point to the parent hence these can be considered child records.

Now consider the following records:

```
{"_id": 1, parent: "", "pValue": ["a", "b", "c"], fieldA: 2},
{"_id": 2, parent: 1, "pValue": [], fieldA: 2},
{"_id": 3, parent: 1, "pValue": [], fieldA: 2},
{"_id": 4, parent: "", "pValue": ["d"], fieldA: 9},
{"_id": 5, parent: 4, "pValue": [], fieldA:2},
{"_id": 6, parent: 4,"pValue": [], fieldA: 9}
```

The above records contain two parents each having 2 associated child records. The query I'm trying to perform involves matching two given parameters. First a value on the pValue. Once I get all the parents with that specific pValue in their array. I then want to match that parent AND all it's associated child records to the fieldA value.

So if given pValue="d" and fieldA=9 I want the following records within the cursor:

```
{"_id": 4, parent: "", "pValue": ["d"], fieldA: 9}
{"_id": 6, parent: 4, "pValue": [],fieldA: 9}
```

**Notes:**

1. Each parent can have many children associated to them.
2. The parent can have a different fieldA value to the child and the query should only then return the child and not the parent

**My Attempt:**

```
 cursor=self.pCollection.aggregate([
      { "$match": {"pValue":{"$in":[pCheck]}},
      {   "$graphLookup" : {
          "from": "pCollection",
          "startWith": "$_id",
          "connectFromField": "_id",
          "connectToField": "parent",
          "as" : "children"
          }
      }])
```

I then got stuck with all the children being associated with the parent as an array without knowing how to upwrap them.

Comment: Can you please show the expected result?

Comment: Hi Styvane, say I want to match on fieldA=2 the result would be just the record {"_id":3,"fieldA":2,"fieldB":8,"pValue":["a","b"],parent:1} however it needs to first have gone through the graphLookup

Comment: Also if the parent record also had a fieldA value of 2 it would return both records I.e. the parent and the child

Comment: OK, please edit your question to add sample document with the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select the documents where that match your query criteria using [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) and filter the "children" array in add an [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) stage.

After [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/)ing, you can use the [`arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt) to *assign* that the item to a field.

```
{ "$match": { "fieldA": 9, "children.fieldA": 9 } },
{ "$addFields": { 
    "children": {
        "$arrayElemAt": [
            { "$filter": { 
                "input": "$children",
                "as": "child",
                "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$child.fieldA", 9 ] }
            }},
            0
         ]
    }
}}
```

Your query will yield something like this:

```
{
    "_id" : 4,
    "parent" : "",
    "pValue" : [ "d" ],
    "fieldA" : 9,
    "children" : { "_id" : 6, "parent" : 4, "pValue" : [ ], "fieldA" : 9 }
}
```

However, with a little faith, you can  get your expected result.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$graphLookup": {
        "from": "collection",
        "startWith": "$_id", 
        "connectFromField": "_id",           
        "connectToField": "parent",     
        "as" : "children"
    }}, 
    { "$match": { "fieldA": 9, "children.fieldA": 9 } }, 
    { "$addFields": { 
        "children": { 
            "$arrayElemAt": [ 
                { "$filter": { 
                    "input": "$children", 
                    "as": "child", 
                    "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$child.fieldA", 9 ] } 
                }}, 
                0 
            ] 
        }
    }}, 
    { "$project": { 
        "children": [
            "$children", 
            { 
                "_id": "$_id", 
                "parent": "$parent", 
                "pValue": "$pValue", 
                "fieldA": "$fieldA" 
            }
        ]
    }}, 
    { "$unwind": "$children" }, 
    { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$children" } }
])
```

which produces something like this:

```
{ "_id" : 6, "parent" : 4, "pValue" : [ ], "fieldA" : 9 }
{ "_id" : 4, "parent" : "", "pValue" : [ "d" ], "fieldA" : 9 }
```

Frankly I don't think this is something you should be doing in your application. The first option is something you can and should live with.

If you really need this, I suggest you [create a view](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createView/) and query the view in your application.

Comment: @tyvane: I was try your script but not working with my db:

db.getCollection('categories').aggregate( [
   {
      $graphLookup: {
         from: "categories",
         startWith: "$CategoryParent",
         connectFromField: "CategoryParent",
         connectToField: "_id",
         as: "testHierarchy"
      }
   },
{ "$match": { "_id": ObjectId('5b4daacce3d25a27c81417f4') } }
]);
Because field: 'CategoryParent' is string and field: '_id' is ObjectId. I don't know how to convert field '_id' with ObjectId type to string

Answer (score 1):

By reversing the query and first matching on fieldA then doing a graphyLookup from parent--> _id (hence mapping the parent into the child) I was able to then associate the children to have their parent's fieldA.

This is the query I ended up with:

```
     cursor=self.collection.aggregate([
          { "$match": {"fieldA":9}},
          { "$graphLookup" : {
            "from": "collection",
            "startWith": "$parent",
            "connectFromField": "parent",
            "connectToField": "_id",
            "as" : "parents"
            }
          },
          { "$project" : {
             "pValue": { "$cond":[ {"$ne":["$pValue",[]]},"$pValue",  
                                     {"$let":{"vars": {"obj": {"$arrayElemAt": ["$parents", 0]}},
                                                               "in": "$$obj.pValue"}}]}
             }
          },
          { "$match": {"pValue":{"$in":["d"]}}}
        ])
```

Comment: Since you are using MongoDB 3.4 use `$switch` instead of `$cond` like I did in the answer to your other question it makes your intention clear.

Comment: Cool thanks for that Styvane I'll change to that. Cheers and thanks a lot for the help

Comment: How can I connectFromFeild in string with connectToField in ObjectId???
Here is my code

    db.getCollection('categories').aggregate( [
       {
          $graphLookup: {
             from: "categories",
             startWith: "$CategoryParent",
             connectFromField: "CategoryParent",
             connectToField: "_id",
             as: "testHierarchy"
          }
       },
    { "$match": { "_id": ObjectId('5b4daacce3d25a27c81417f4') } }
    ]);

connectFromField: "CategoryParent" => stringconnectToField: "_id" => ObjectId